# Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec() will run asynchronously?

Tags: java, multithreading, process, runtime, runtime.exec

Starting from this situation:

```
        for (String certificateSha1:certificateSha1List){
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String [] {"security", "delete-certificate", "-Z", certificateSha1}, null , new File(this.workDir+"") );      
            
            Helpers.asynchOutputWrite(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()), standardOutput);
        }
```

And noting that Helpers.asynchOutputWrite generates a new thread which will write the parametrized stream into that output file. Will these threads overlap themselves writing into the file? or will the next iteration of the for wait until exec() method has finalized?

Answer (score 3):

Unless you call `p.waitFor();` your process will happily run concurrently alongside the process that it spawned (`p`).

Comment: so it is enought to add p.waitFor(); after Helpers.asynchOutputWrite ?

Comment: @NullPointerException if you want to wait until the process has finished, yes.